# Using jQuery to count all inputs nested in div

Tags: jquery, validation, input, count, children

**I have a setup basically like this:**

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="field_shell">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field">
    </div> 
    <div class="field_shell">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="name" class="field"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Except on a larger scale, there are three sets of `#container`, each `#container` holding several (and varying amounts of) div.field_shell elements. Most div.field_shell hold only one input, but a few do hold two separate input elements.

My issue is how I can count the number of input elements in each #content. Bonus points for giving some insight on the best method of checking if each input in each #container div is filled, and returning specific results if so.

I assume `.length` is viable here, but I am stumped. Especially on checking the "status" of each `#container` (by status, I mean if each input within that `#container` is filled, and not empty).

Thank you guys so much for reading through, and thank you more for helping :)

Comment: In your html i dont saw #content

Comment: You might have gotten the length of the input element, which is 0 if unfilled.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to use jQuery,  I've changed your HTML code a bit to make it work.  Ids should be unique.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="field_shell">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field_shell">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="field"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery code to count for each `#container`,  It will traverse the DOM tree and return all elements that match `input`

```
var inputs = $("#container").find($("input") );
console.log(inputs.length)
```

If you want to check for filled input elements, you can look at the `element.length` property.  To count for multiple containers, you could run a loop to handle each `#container` and nest the code above in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var FieldShellelements = $("#container .field_shell");
        for (i = 0; i < FieldShellelements.length; i++) {
            alert($(FieldShellelements[i]).children('input').length);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/KSDXu/)

I hope this is what you want

**HTML**

```
    <div id="container">

 <div class="field_shell">

   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="demo" class="field">

 </div>

 <div class="field_shell">

   <label for="age">Age</label>
   <input type="text" name="age" id="name" class="field">

 </div>

</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    var count=0;
$('#container').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
        count+=1
        alert("Filled Value="+$(this).val());
    }
});
alert("Total Input Count="+$('#container').find('input[type="text"]').length+"//Filled Inputs Count="+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keeps IDs unique on a page, since `$("#container")` will only ever match the first instance (whereas `$("[id='container']")` will pick up all of them).

```js
// Gather all containers that have all inputs filled
var allInputsFilled = $("[id='container']").filter(function () {
        var allFilled = true,
            inputs = $(this).find("input");

        inputs.each(function () {
            // !val() equates to true when the value is empty
            // '' is a falsy value, inverted with ! not operator
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                allFilled = false;
                return false; // break out of loop early
            }
        });

        return allFilled; 
    });
```

`allInputsFilled` will contain all `#container` divs that have all their inputs filled. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/aNokaZa/1/).